# First setup of Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: raspbian, wifi, ssh, pi-zero-w, putty

I've just bought a new Raspberry Pi Zero W v1.1 2017 and i already have a connection problem with putty over ssh.

Things i've done so far:

- downloaded 2017-09-07-raspbian-stretch.img and burned with Win32DiskImager on micro sd
- created an `ssh` file in the root folder
- created `wpa_supplicant.conf` file containing:

  `network={
  ssid="Redmi4N"
  psk="12345678"
  key_mgmt=WPA2-Personal
  }`

*also tried with `key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK` or without that line

When i try to connect with putty at raspberrypi i get the following error:

> Unable to open connection to raspberrypi Host does not exist.

*same thing for raspberrypi.local as a host

Then, i've tried to check the connections with Advanced IP Scanner as i have read on forums but still nothing; it is not shown in there.

Am i doing something wrong? What else shoul i try?

PS:Using Windows 10 and the latest version of putty.

Comment: Did you enable `ssh`? See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) You don't need `key_mgmt` for normal network. Another possible issue is the unusual image size with recent Raspbian - using `Etcher` avoids this.

Comment: AFAIK Windows 10 doesn't support `Zero-conf`out of the box, try entering IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspbian Stretch has some 'tweaks' in the wpa_supplicant file before it will connect.

You need to add a dummy network connection.

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=AU
network={
scan_ssid=1
ssid="NetworkName"
psk="Password"
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
#fake network workaround for headless Raspberry Pi Zero
network={
ssid="fakessid"
psk="fakepass"
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

or you could use the Open Source Tool I have developed and host on GitHub
[Raspberry-Pi-Zero-Wifi-Setup-Tool](https://github.com/RabbitGray/Raspberry-Pi-Zero-Wifi-Setup-Tool)

Comment: Why do you keep posting this? What evidence or reference do you have? The normal setup works OK for the rest of us.

Comment: i've done that plus removing `key_mgmt=WPA2-Personal` and it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Milliways If it helps people, and works for people, whats your issue?

Comment: This just becomes one of the urban myths, which waste people's time, and don't actually help them. There are lots of them in the Pi world. If you put your finger in your left ear before booting the Zero it may help, but I wouldn't recommend it. I am quite sure if the OP just deleted the `key_mgmt` it would have worked. Many of the problems people post are from following incomplete or inaccurate tutorials.

Comment: Well I cannot headless boot a Rpi Zero W 1.3 without it.

Comment: Please provide the hardware and firmware versions that this unusual configuration works on. Tested on Pi Zero W v1.1 with no success. There is no pi Zero W v1.3 as of 11-08-2017, only the older pi Zero v1.3 (without the 'W')

Comment: Works on my 9 Pi Zero W v1.1

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be over complicating the setup, which often introduces problems.

- Download and write the image to card
- Boot the image and change the default password
- Enable SSH
- Install wpagui and manage your required WiFi network, obtaining an IP
- Use putty to connect to the Pi by IP

Windows 10 can now run Linux Subsystem (Ubuntu CLI) which can terminal SSH straight to the Pi.

Using 'Fing' (to scan) and 'JuiceSSH' (for SSH!) on an Android phone/tablet,  connected to the same network, is perfect for quick tweaks or bedtime connections.

Answer (score 0):

1. go to Add/Remove programs and uninstall all Bonjour and Bonjour print services
2. Instead of the registry edit, the group policy editor can be used:

launch gpedit.msc
Navigate to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Network > DNS Client
Enable the "Turn off Multicast Name Resolution" policy.

3. Reinstall bonjour print services.
   Now you should be able to connect via raspberrypi.local in Putty